# How to automatically update a PDF viewed on the right whenever the corresponding EPS is changed on the left?

Tags: visual-studio-code, postscript, vscode-tasks

I am using Visual Studio Code to learn PostScript language.

[image]

I use the following `task.json` to convert EPS to PDF.

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "EPS",
            "command": "ps2pdf",
            "args": [
                "${file}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And my EPS is

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 10 10 300 300

%%BeginProlog
/inch {72 mul} def
/cm {2.54 div inch} def
%%EndProlog


newpath
    1 cm 1 cm moveto
    9 cm 0 cm rlineto
    0 cm  9 cm rlineto
    -9 cm 0 cm rlineto
    9 cm 9 cm rlineto
closepath
5 setlinewidth
stroke
showpage
%%EOF
```

## Question

How to automatically update a PDF viewed on the right whenever the corresponding EPS is changed on the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you've figured something out in the last 2 years-- but for anyone else who stumbles on this like I did, here is a snippet of how I did it with TypeScript for my résumé written in LaTeX-- I'm sure one could apply this to PostScript:

**package.json**:

```json
{
  "name": "resume",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "ts-node watch.ts",
    "generate": "pdflatex -jobname=resume resume.tex"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.5.1",
    "chokidar": "^3.5.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1"
  }
}
```

**watch.ts**:

```js
import { watch } from "chokidar";
import { exec } from "child_process";

// Files to watch for change
const watchFiles: string[] = [
  'resume.tex',
  '_header.tex',
  'TLCresume.sty',
  'sections/**/*.tex',
]

// Watch for changes in the files specified above
const watcher = watch(watchFiles)

function buildPDF() {
  // Execute the 'generate' script in package.json
  // This will run the 'pdflatex' command to generate the PDF
  exec('npm run generate', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
      // node couldn't execute the command
      return;
    }

    console.log("PDF generated!")
  });
}

// Build PDF once at the start
buildPDF();
let lastBuildTime: number = Date.now();

watcher.on('all', (event, path) => {
  if (Date.now() - lastBuildTime < 1000) {
    // Don't build PDF if it was just built less than a second ago
    return;
  } else {
    console.log(`${event} @ ${path}`);
  }

  buildPDF();
  lastBuildTime = Date.now();
});
```

Then:

1. Install the dependencies in package.json using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/) with `npm install`.
2. Change the "generate" script in `package.json` to whatever command is appropriate for generating your PostScript PDF.
3. Change the `watchFiles` array to include paths/RegEx for your PostScript files.
4. Finally, run `npm run watch` to refresh the PDF in VSCode whenever you save your file(s)!